# (MacBook Pro) Wi-Fi becomes slow only when charger plugged in

Tags: network, wifi, charging

I'm having weird issues with Wi-Fi in the basement of my girlfriends place. I originally thought it was the thick concrete walls blocking the Wi-Fi from the router upstairs so I bought a repeater which did increase the signal strength but did not fix the issue.

When my laptop is unplugged the internet is fast on both my phone and my laptop downstairs. When I plug the charger in page loads slow to a crawl on my phone and my laptop. I've tried different power sockets and removing all other devices from the extension cable but the problem remains.

I thought interference could be a problem so I enabled 5GHz on my router but unfortunately it doesn't reach down here, so I'm stuck using 2.4GHz.

It's a MacBook Pro Early 2011. When I'm at my own house, I have no issues with Wi-Fi when the laptop is charging.

I'm stumped. Maybe the power that comes from the wall is introducing interference? I'm using an Australian charger with an adapter on a German wall socket if that helps.

**Added Speed-test results**

**Test 1 Without Charger**
Download `21.00Mbps` Upload `4.79Mbps`

**Test 2 With Charger**
---- Download `_6.72Mbps` Upload `3.35Mbps`

**Test 3 Without Charger**
Download `22.61Mbps` Upload `4.70Mbps`

**Test 4 With Charger** 
---- Download `21.85Mbps` Upload `4.59Mbps`

**Test 5 Without Charger**
Download `22.69Mbps` Upload `4.50Mbps`

**Test 6 With Charger**
---- Download `_2.89Mbps` Upload *Failed*

Comment: Could you do [speed tests](http://www.speedtest.net/) both with your charger plugged in and without ? You should do that 2-3 times to see if you get approximatively the same results. Then edit your question with this results so that other people may see how much this is impacting.

Comment: Sure have updated the question. Not sure why test 4 was quick with the charger in but it is definitely consistently slower with the charger plugged in.

Comment: Is it a *genuine* Apple charger?

Comment: Yes it's genuine

Comment: Have you contacted Apple support?